# Angular modal: add buttons from button list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-modal

Trying to add buttons from button list for each modal.

Script:

```
  var buttonList2 = [{displayName: 'Save', class: 'save'},
                     {displayName: 'Cancel', class: 'cancel'}];
```

Html:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" ng-repeat = "item in buttonList" ng-class="{{item.class}}">{{item.displayName}}</button>
```

Each button has its own class, so I added in list class property.
But ng-class doesn't see {{item.class}}

And I can't add functions to these buttons. I tried this:

```
  $('.cancel').attr('ng-click','cancel()');
  $compile($('.cancel'))($scope);
  $('.save').attr('ng-click','save()');
  $compile($('.save'))($scope);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NeLthqUuZtw0VyVzd0Ig?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried `ng-class="item.class"`?

Comment: It works if I add css. But still can't dynamically add functions to buttons.

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically apply css classes use `ng-class="item.class"` without `{{}}`.

To add callbacks to your buttons you may add a additional property to your buttons that holds the specific function:

```
var buttonList2 = [
    {displayName: 'Save', class: 'save', callback: function(){alert('saving');}},
    {displayName: 'Cancel', class: 'cancel', callback: function(){alert('cancelling');}}
];
```

In your `ng-repeat` you can then apply them with:

```
<button type="button" ng-repeat="item in buttonList2" ng-click="item.callback()" ng-class="item.class">{{item.displayName}}</button>
```

Comment: If I want to do like this: {displayName: 'Cancel', class: 'cancel', callback: cancel()} http://plnkr.co/edit/NeLthqUuZtw0VyVzd0Ig?p=preview it crashes

Comment: Try `{displayName: 'Cancel', class: 'cancel', callback: $scope.cancel}` instead. See: http://plnkr.co/edit/P7O85aoXqxjzdvLKnzG8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best in a comment, but I can't give a comment yet.

Is it possible / bad practice to do:

```
class="{{item.class}}"
```